# Android: How to: create a service running in the background and call Handler.sendMessage(..)

Tags: android, service

I want to use the android.app.Service (not IntentService, not AsyncTask) to run my long running process and calling Handler.sendMessage(..) during the process.

using the below code is enough (Service's onCreate method)?

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.w(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "DEBUG MODE - CallbackImpl handleError() called");
            // get the location information (lat,lon,altitude etc..)
            // then, call callback methods.
            _locationProvider.getLocation(_locationCallbackImpl);
        }

    }).start();
}

private final LocationCallbackImpl _locationCallbackImpl = new LocationCallbackImpl();

private class LocationCallbackImpl
    implements 
        LocationCallback
        {
    @Override
    public void done() {
        Log.i(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "LocationCallbackImpl done() called");
        // switch to UI thread
        _handler.sendMessage(_handler.obtainMessage(DONE_MESSAGE));
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ReturnCode returnCode) {
        Log.e(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "LocationCallbackImpl handleError() called:" + returnCode.name());

        // send a message to display the error
            _handler.sendMessage(_handler.obtainMessage(ERROR_MESSAGE, returnCode));
    }

    @Override
    public void handleSuccess(Location location) {
        Log.i(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "LocationCallbackImpl handleSuccess() called");
            _handler.sendMessage(_handler.obtainMessage(LOCATION_MESSAGE, location));
    }
}
```

And would like also to ask you guys, if all the callbacks will be called on the above created thread?

How can I check if they are really running on that thread? is there a way to check it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `getter and setter of Handler inside service` and set this handler from the activity where you want to receive it's notification.

Comment: would you revise my sample codes to apply that getter/setter for the Handler?